# Error when opening my packaged Node.js app, no error when opening the unpackaged app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, path, electron-packager

My app is working as long as I start it using the terminal/cmd line.
Now I've packaged the app using the electron packager, but I get the following two errors:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'settings.json'
```

And:

```
Uncaught Exception:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ReadFileContext.fs.readFile [as callback] (/Users/zeno/Applications/splyr-cop/dist/splyr-cop-darwin-x64/splyr-cop.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/main.js:202:21)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:359:13)
```

These errors only happen in the packaged version of the app.
I assume it has something to do with the paths of settings.json and billing.json:

```
const path = require('path');
var settings = path.resolve('./settings.json');
var billing = path.resolve('./billing.json');
```

[Both .json are placed directly in the folder of the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiAKh.png)

According to the FAQ of the electron-packager, this is a common error [(see here)](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why-isnt-the-relative-path-in-my-app-code-working).

They recommend something like this:

> `AppName
>
> ├── package.json
>
> ├── data -> somedata.json
>
> └── src -> main.js
>
> In src/main.js, you would access data/somedata.json similar to this:
>
> ```
> const path = require('path');
> const jsonFilename = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'data', 'somedata.json');
> console.log(require(jsonFilename));
> ```

Also tried using const instead of var, but this just leads to another error. It should be possible for the app to make changes to settings.json.

Line 202 looks like this (202 is: profiles = JSON.parse(data);)

```
ipcMain.on('setupUi', function(event) {
  fs.readFile('settings.json', (err, data) => {
              if(err){throw err;} else{
              settings = JSON.parse(data);
              mainWin.webContents.send('setupUi', JSON.parse(data));
              }
  });
  fs.readFile( 'billing.json', (err, data) => {
    profiles = JSON.parse(data);
    for (p in profiles) {
      switch(profiles[p].country) {
        case 'US':
          profilesUS[p] = profiles[p];
          break;
        case 'UK':
          profilesUK[p] = profiles[p];
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Also tried "var settings = path.resolve(__dirname, 'settings.json');" etc., nothing worked.

**Could it be that something is wrong with "settings = JSON.parse(data);"?**

I'd really appreciate any help, I've been trying to fix this for hours.

Comment: Your JSON files are valid?

Comment: @Sombrero yes, they work for the unpackaged app.